# Can I use Rust / Yew / Trunk to generate just a DOM node and script for use in HTML templates?

Tags: html, templates, rust, yew, trunk-rs

### TLDR

Total n00b with rust, yew and trunk.

I want to find out how to rust, yew and trunk to build an HTML file containing just one DOM node, not a whole HTML page.

### Background

Day-to-day, I use Django, the python web framework. Its admin console uses HTML template rendering, and an example of a template might look like this:

```
{% extends 'django_twined/question_changeform.html' %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {% if show_set_active %}
        <li><a href="?set_active=True">Set active</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Where in this example the `{% %}` and `{{ }}` get evaluated at render time into a valid HTML structure (from other template files), and the `<li>` is an extra node that gets added to the DOM.

Instead of a vanilla `li` element, I want to build a complex DOM node using Rust/Yew/Trunk. Then I can `include` the resulting head and body elements file in a django template, something like:

```
{% extends 'django_twined/question_changeform.html' %}

{% block head %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <!-- Include the scripts generated by trunk build -->
    {% include 'my-dom-node-head.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <!-- Include the elements generated by trunk build -->
    {% include 'my-dom-node-body.html' %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

### Where I'm at

I've used the yew starter app to get myself to an app. The input `index.html` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Yew App</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

And the `main.rs` file looks like:

```rs
use yew::prelude::*;

enum Msg {
    AddOne,
}

struct Model {
    value: i64,
}

impl Component for Model {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        Self {
            value: 0,
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _ctx: &Context<Self>, msg: Self::Message) -> bool {
        match msg {
            Msg::AddOne => {
                self.value += 1;
                // the value has changed so we need to
                // re-render for it to appear on the page
                true
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self, ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        // This gives us a component's "`Scope`" which allows us to send messages, etc to the component.
        let link = ctx.link();
        html! {
            <div>
                <button onclick={link.callback(|_| Msg::AddOne)}>{ "+1" }</button>
                <p>{ self.value }</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::start_app::<Model>();
}
```

After `trunk build`, the output `index.html` looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Yew App</title>
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/yew-app-caccf6c60742c530_bg.wasm"
      as="fetch"
      type="application/wasm"
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/yew-app-caccf6c60742c530.js" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import init from "/yew-app-caccf6c60742c530.js";
      init("/yew-app-caccf6c60742c530_bg.wasm");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Where next?

So basically I need to get the `<link>` and `<script>` elements added by `trunk build` and put them into my template.

What should I do next? Would you suggest I try to:

- Get `trunk build --filehash false` to output deterministic `.js` and `.wasm` file names without the hash (`caccf6c60742c530` in this case) so that I can directly write the `includes` into my template (I'm concerned this will cause me development problems down the road)?
- Get `trunk build` to output separate head link and body script?
- Post-process the output `index.html` to extract the inserted scripts?
- Alter `main.rs` in some way to output only what I need/want?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but here is a rust crate [tera](https://tera.netlify.app/) that could help you. It's a templating engine very similar to one used by django.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze that might be extremely useful to me in future, thank you - although agree that it might not be quite a fit here.

Comment: What would be extremely cool is if there were some kind of tera-yew plugin that allowed you to generate templates for yew then render them with tera. It'd work exactly like React where you can just add react to whatever node in the HTML you want.